# Change order of characters in string randomly keeping the format in python

Tags: string, python-2.7, random, character

I have to mask some data but it is important to keep the format of it.

So I have differents strings like:

```
x = "0 1-111-555"
y = "000000-2022-1000253"
z = "01-702-1424"
t = "0SC9496439"
```

These may contain dashes,blanks..and other characters.

What I want is to generate randomly a **new string** **keeping the format**. So the result should look like:

```
x = "4 5-421-999"
y = "121212-1994-0909091"
z = "10-JLF-1800"
t = "XXX456TTT1"
```

**CONSIDERATIONS**

1. It does not matter if the new string contains letters or numbers as long as it keeps the original format.
2. It must keep the positions of the characters that are neither numbers nor letters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the problem.

The solutions is:

```
import random
import re

letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW'
numbers = '0123456789'
seq = '0    -890  EROOOTR  4-750-595-789 N  9'
length = len(seq) 

for i in range(len(seq)):
    digit = re.search('[0-9]',seq[i])
    alpha = re.search('[a-zA-Z]',seq[i])
    nonAlphaDigit = re.search('[^a-zA-Z0-9_]',seq[i])
    if digit and nonAlphaDigit== None :
        w = random.choice(numbers)
        seq = seq.replace(seq[i],w)
    if alpha and nonAlphaDigit== None :
        w = random.choice(letters)
        seq = seq.replace(seq[i],w)
print seq
```